# Variable length input with Keras/Tensorflow Serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a Keras model that will be exported to TF serving for text classification. The model supports variable length inputs (or at least, I can feed in inputs of any length when evaluating), but I can't figure out how to describe this when generating the classification signature for TF serving

Currently, I'm doing:

```
  # Create the input tensors
  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
  feature_configs = {'input': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)}
  tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)
  output_tensor = model(tf_example['input'])

  # Create the prediction output tensors
  values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(output_tensor, len(binarizer.classes_))
  table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_tensor(tf.constant(binarizer.classes_))
  prediction_classes = table.lookup(tf.to_int64(indices))

  # Generate a classification signature
  signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.classification_signature_def(
    serialized_tf_example,
    prediction_classes,
    values
  )
```

However, this fails because `VarLenFeature` parses to a `SparseTensor`, which the embedding layer does not support. However, if I change `VarLenFeature` to a `FixedLenFeature`, then I have to provide fixed inputs to the tensorflow model, which is suboptimal for this case.

The actual error I get when trying this is:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("ParseExample/ParseExample:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("ParseExample/ParseExample:1", shape=(?,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=Tensor("ParseExample/ParseExample:2", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I'm not sure what else I can do to inform TF serving that variable length inputs are supported in the graph - or if this is even possible when using keras.

Comment: Ok. I figured out something that works. By taking the `SparseTensor` and converting it to a tensor with `tf.sparse.to_dense(sparse)`, I have it working. Though I'm not sure what the pitfalls are with this approach. I'll leave this question open briefly to see if someone can shine some light.

Comment: The issue is that a dense tensor consumes way more memory than a sparse one, especially if the majority of the sparse tensor is empty (as you would expect in a sparse tensor). If your batches are small enough this might not be an issue.